# Why can't a UITableViewCell instance be used as computed property?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm can't seem to make this work, the cell's text labels appear empty:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell {

    var c:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell

    if c == nil {
        c = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    }

    return c!
}
```

However,if I do this, everything works fine:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell

if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")

}
```

I don't understand why. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thank you!

EDIT: The code using the computed property

```
var cell:UITableViewCell {

    var c:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell

    if c == nil {
        c = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        c!.selectionStyle = .None
        c!.backgroundColor = Theme.Colors.viewBackgroundColor
        c!.textLabel?.textColor = Theme.Colors.fadedTextColor
        c!.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: kFontDINCondRegular, size: 21.0)
        c!.detailTextLabel?.textColor = Theme.Colors.fadedTextColor
        c!.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: kFontDINCondRegular, size: 21.0)
    }

    return c!
}

switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.lastMonthDescription
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.model.foldersContactedLastMonth.stringValue
case 1:
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.currentMonthDescription
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.model.foldersContactedCurrentMonth.stringValue
case 2:
    cell.textLabel?.text = FSLocalizedString(Localizable.THIS_WEEK).uppercaseString
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.model.foldersContactedCurrentWeek.stringValue
case 3:
    cell.textLabel?.text = FSLocalizedString(Localizable.TODAY).uppercaseString
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.model.foldersContactedToday.stringValue
default: break

}

return cell
```

Comment: We need to see the code in which you are _using_ the `cell` computed property.

Comment: Edited the question with the code I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your goal is, but with your implementation you are dequeueing a new cell every time you access the `cell` computed property. That means with these two lines:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.lastMonthDescription
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.model.foldersContactedLastMonth.stringValue
```

You are are creating two different cells. **You are then returning an entirely new cell in the final return.**

Computed properties are just that, they are computed every time you try to access them instead of actually being stored in memory.

You may try a lazy variable instead:

```
lazy var cell: UITableViewCell = {
    // blah
    return cell
}()
```

Notice that I am not using a computed property here. Instead, I am assigning to the result of an inline closure that creates the cell. By making it lazy, it does not call the closure until the first time `cell` is accessed but then the result is stored in memory so you can continue to manipulate the same cell instance instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: Ah!! Thank you. I understand computed properties better now :) That did it.